# What is bias node in googlenet and how to remove it?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch

I am new to deep learning, i want to build a model that can identify similar images, i am reading [classification is a Strong Baseline for Deep Metric Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.12649.pdf) research paper. and here is they used the phrase: `"remove the bias term inthe last linear layer"`. i have no idea what is bias term is and how to remove it from `googlenet` or other pretrained models. `if someone help me out with this it would be great!` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the layer n outputs, a linear neural network computes a linear combination of the layer n-1 output for each layer n output, adds a scalar constant value to each layer n output (the bias term), and then applies an activation function. In pytorch, one could disable the bias in a linear layer using:

```
layer = torch.nn.Linear(n_in_features, n_out_features, bias=False)
```

To overwrite the existing structure of, say, the googlenet included in torchvision.models defined [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/googlenet.html#googlenet), you can simply override the last fully connected layer after initialization:

```
from torchvision.models import googlenet
num_classes = 1000 # or whatever you need it to be

model = googlenet(num_classes)
model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(1000,num_classes,bias = False)
```

Comment: I think you mean `bias=False` instead of `pretrained=False`.

Comment: Good call @ GoodDeeds

Comment: Thanks @DerekG for help. i think it was a silly question to ask after knowing this, i could have done research before asking questions :)